# How to print integers into list form

Tags: python, list, printing, int

I am kind of new to python. I am trying to print only the integers in a list divisible by 5. Which I have done. But I want the output to be a list, not only the integers.

My Code:

```
list = [2,4,5,10,12]
for x in list:
if not x % 5 == 0:
    print (x)
```

I want the output to look like:
[2,4,12]

But intsead it looks like:

2,

4,

12

Is there any commands to print the "x" items into a list? Like print(list[x])?

Comment: I used the end command. I did print(x, end =", "), That gives me: 2, 4, 12,... But I want it to be in a "list"

Comment: Do a _list comprehension_: `[x for x in lst if x%5]` - Also don't shadow builtin names such as `list`. The list comprehension creates a new list which you can then print or use in any way you see fit.

Comment: I have to use the for and if statements for this assignment. How would I use the print command to print the list as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect your answers in a new list and then print that list. You can do this by creating an empty list and using the `.append()` method to add items to that list.

```
my_list = [2,4,5,10,12]
answers = []
for x in my_list:
    if not x % 5 == 0:
        answers.append(x)
print(answers)
```

A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=comprehensions#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) is another option. A list comprehension is a powerful shortcut that creates the second list for you automatically.

For this problem, you could use:

```
my_list = [2,4,5,10,12]
answers = [x for x in my_list if x%5 != 0]
print(answers)
```

which accomplishes the same thing as the `for` loop in fewer lines. In this case, you may have to use the `for` version, but you may want to use a comprehension in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved that. I hope it helps:

```
list1 = [2,4,5,10,12]
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    if not x % 5 == 0:
        list2.append(x)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP, using the following numbers [2,4,5,10,12] is "trying to print only the integers in a list divisible by 5.  I want the output to look like: [2,4,12]"

Generally, "numbers divisible by 5" are capable of being divided by 5 without a remainder.  From the given list the output would be [5,10]

```
data = [2, 4, 5, 10, 12]

# Print numbers evenly divisible by 5.
print([i for i in data if i % 5 == 0])

[5, 10]
```

From the output provided by the OP, he's looking for numbers where there is a remainder after dividing by 5.

```
data = [2, 4, 5, 10, 12]

# Print numbers not evenly divisible by 5.
print([i for i in data if i % 5])

[2, 4, 12]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.